# Como situar dos tablas en la misma linea en ezpdf creation (PHP)

Tags: php

Estuve viendo la documentación de ese **framework** para PHP y no logro poner dos tablas juntas en la misma fila. se podra?

La documentacion esta en este [Link](http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/pdf-php-code/readme.php)

```
<?php
    include_once '../src/Cezpdf.php';
    $pdf = new CezPDF("a4");

    $pdf->selectFont('Helvetica');

    $data = array(
     array('num'=>1,'name'=>'gandalf','type'=>'wizard')
    ,array('num'=>2,'name'=>'bilbo','type'=>'hobbit','url'=>'asd')
    ,array('num'=>3,'name'=>'frodo','type'=>'hobbit')
    ,array('num'=>4,'name'=>'saruman','type'=>'bad dude','url'=>'asdd')
    ,array('num'=>5,'name'=>'sauron','type'=>'really bad dude')
    );
    $cols = array('num'=>'No', 'type'=>'Type','name'=>'<i>Alias</i>');
    $coloptions = array('num'=> array('justification'=>'right'), 'name'=> array('justification'=>'left'),'type'=> array('justification'=>'center'));

    $pdf->ezText("<b>GRIDLINE</b>", 12);

    $pdf->ezText("<b>using 'showLines' option - DEPRECATED</b>\n", 10);

    $pdf->ezText("\nDefault: showLines = 1\n", 10);
//esta es la primera tabla
    $pdf->ezTable($data, $cols, "", array('xPos' => 'coordinate','xOrientation' => 'right'));
//esta es la segunda
    $pdf->ezTable($data, $cols, "", array('xPos' => 'right','xOrientation' => 'left')); 
    $pdf->ezStream();
    ?>
```

Comment: Realmente no he usado esa librería, ¿soporta tags html?, si lo soporta podrías hacerlo mediante html y css

Comment: Intente con tags, pero tampoco me deja

Comment: Coloca el código que has intentado hasta ahora, para que otros usuarios puedan reproducir el problema y así poder ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: Ahi modifique la publicacion y puse el codigo

Comment: Probé el código y leí la documentación, al parecer esa librería es bastante básica, solo soporta algunos tags de html, y no permite mayores opciones al crear la tabla, te recomiendo usar otra librería, por ejemplo **tcpdf** que da mayores opciones de personalización al soportar html y css

Comment: Buenisimo, estaré probando esa libreria, muchas gracias !

Comment: Ok de nada, agregaré una respuesta en base al comentario, si te sirvió la marcas como solución a tu problema así otros usuarios también la pueden encontrar útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probé el código y leí la documentación, al parecer esa librería es bastante básica, solo soporta algunos tags de html, y no permite mayores opciones al crear la tabla, te recomiendo usar otra librería, por ejemplo **TCPDF** que da mayores opciones de personalización al soportar **html y css**.

Por ejemplo en tcpdf podridas hacer algo así para crear tablas.

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">COL 1 - ROW 1<br />COLSPAN 3</td>
        <td>COL 2 - ROW 1</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">COL 2 - ROW 2 - COLSPAN 2<br />text line<br />text line<br />text line<br />text line</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>COL 3 - ROW 3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

En este link esta el ejemplo completo:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps

Y aquí esta el ejemplo en PDF:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.pdf